# Remove blank line at EOF batch script

Tags: batch-file, replace

I can't figure out how to remove a blank line generated from the `find /c` command. I have an integer value being outputted to a text file, and after that value there is an extra line. Running the find command on its own will also produce the new line. Is there some type of flag I can set to prevent this? If not, how can remove the blank line?

```
@echo off 
setlocal cd /D T:/Product/"Test Certificates" 
forfiles /m *.* -d 0|find /c """">"J:\scoreboard\currently_built_number.txt"
```

So the script is seeing how many of a product we built today based on when the file was created. That number is being piped to a text file. It is there that I want to remove the extra line under the number that is outputted

Comment: You should show your current code, perhaps it's better to use `findstr` here and avoid pipes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f %%f in ('forfiles /m *.* -d 0^|find /c /v ""') do (
    < nul set /p "buildNumber=%%f" >"J:\scoreboard\currently_built_number.txt"
)
```

Comment: So I am fairly new to batch scripting, I get the first part. It is saying for each file in the file set returned from the this command, do this. What I don't understand is the `nul set /p "buildNumber-%%f"`. I know that the /p gets rid of that extra space, but what is the `nul` and why do you need to set a variable? It works, so I am not questioning your logic. Just trying to understand :)

Comment: @dge888: more or less it works that way: `set /p var=prompt` + enter will output the text in prompt (it is asking for data, this is what `set /p` is used for) without an aditional `crlf`. The `<nul` is a redirect to input data to the var (feed the `set` prompt) from nul, returning nothing into the var but simulating the enter. The value of the prompt (rememeber it is echoed without `crlf`) is then redirected with `>file` to get the desired value into file.